# 1440 x 900 screen resolution disappeared in my Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I recently bought a 19" LCD and the resolution automatically changed to 1440 x 900 when I plugged it in. I was fooling around with the resolutions then 1440 x 900 disappeared. Now I'm using 1280 x 1024, ITS BAD!!

How can I get this resolution back?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the LCD screen video drivers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/112303/why-does-the-screen-resolution-of-1440x900-suddenly-disappears-from-intel-gma-con)?

Otherwise: Somethimes you have to first choose the aspect ratio. 1280x1024 is 4:3 while 1440x900 is 16:10.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a couple of times.  In each instance it was a case of the graphics card not communicating properly with the monitor.

The solution was to disconnect each end of the video cable and reseat it properly.  After a reboot, the missing resolutions were again available in the settings tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems setting 1440×900 after few days then try this – it worked for me. Maybe it could work for you.

1. Unplug the monitor cable (VGA/DVI) from computer
2. Unplug the power cable from your monitor
3. Replug the monitor cable (VGA/DVI) to computer
4. Replug the power cable to your monitor

**Important:** Perform these steps while the computer is totally switched on (i.e. after logging into Windows).

Comment: By "CPU" you mean computer? It is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the refresh rate in windows for the monitor first before that resolution is available for selection.